# Average time it takes to test a strike?

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, quant-trading-strategies, probability, historical-data

My question can be confusing so it’s better I explain it with an example.

Let’s say I sell a strangle. That is with call at +27 delta and put at -27 delta. With 30 days to expiration.

Is it possible that there is a mathematical formula to estimate the average time it takes for the underlying to reach either of the short strikes? If so, is the result consistent/useful(i.e it’s coefficient of variation of the average is low)?

Example: maybe with the formula it shows that after 90% of the 30 days has passed then one of the strikes would have been reached.

If there is no maths formula, then I think use of historical data or Monte Carlo simulations could solve the problem. Is there any research paper, or article on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is still quite unclear. Assuming you want to solve it mathematically you need to provide at least some assumptions regarding the underlying process/distribution.

Assuming you want to solve it in a Black-Scholes framework (not applicable to real life trading) your questions boils down to stopping time (with two bounds). The density for this has been derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533948/density-of-hitting-time-for-a-two-sided-barrior-for-brownian-motion-with-drift?rq=1).
From this you could calculate the expected value of the stopping time, however this will be overestimated for far OTM strikes because of the underlying distribution assumption.